# Creation of files in the wrong directory under studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have migrated my Android project to Gradle and Android Studio, mainly to include flavors.
However, now when I create for example a fragment with New -> Android Component it puts the files in the wrong directory and resources cannot be found.

For example. I add a fragment under org.idoms.iDomsAndroid.fragments I get the following package name:

```
package .........src.org.idoms.iDomsAndroid.fragments;
```

Then the resource files are created under:

```
/idoms-android/src/main/res/layout/
```

instead of

```
/res/layout
```

My gradle file looks as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 6
    }

    productFlavors {
        iDomsTest {
            packageName 'org.idoms.iDomsAndroidTest'
        }
        iDomsAndroidDev {
            packageName 'org.idoms.iDomsAndroidDev'
        }
        iDomsAndroid {
            packageName 'org.idoms.iDomsAndroid'
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
               XXX
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        iDomsAndroidDebug.setRoot('product-flavors/iDomsAndroid')
        iDomsAndroidRelease.setRoot('product-flavors/iDomsAndroid')
        iDomsAndroidDevDebug.setRoot('product-flavors/iDomsAndroidDev')
        iDomsAndroidDevRelease.setRoot('product-flavors/iDomsAndroidDev')
        iDomsTestDebug.setRoot('product-flavors/iDomsTest')
        iDomsTestRelease.setRoot('product-flavors/iDomsTest')    
    }
    println "main: " + android.sourceSets.main.res.srcDirs

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        println variant.name + ": " + android.sourceSets[variant.name].res.srcDirs
    }

    android.productFlavors.all { flavor ->
        println flavor.name + ": " + android.sourceSets[flavor.name].res.srcDirs
    }

    android.buildTypes.all { buildType ->
        println buildType.name + ": " + android.sourceSets[buildType.name].res.srcDirs
    }
}
```

Is there something I should change to het the IDE to work properly again?

Comment: I've had problems using Android Studio on projects with the Eclipse directory structure ("src" and "res" at the root level).  Once I adopted the maven structure I had much better luck (i.e. move "src" to "src/main/java" and "res" to "src/main/res".  I finally just decided to adopt Android Studio and not look back!  Sorry if that's not the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I was using Idea anyway, so the new structure will work there as well if needed. Is there an official help/manual on what it should be, or just the above as you indicated?

Comment: Android Studio and Gradle can for the most part handle the Eclipse-style directory structure, but the template-based wizards such as New > Android Component aren't that smart yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Gradle help files for Android Studio.  Studio (really, Gradle) adopts a different directory structure for your files under /src/main as you are seeing.  This makes the projects non-backwards compatible with Eclipse.

Comment: I changed the structure, and everything seems to work ok now.

Comment: Glad you were able to get it working!  Best of luck with your project!